# Как полностью удалить свой вопрос здесь?

Tags: поддержка, stackoverflow

Я задал вопрос на stackoverflow по упражнению с сайта sql-ex.ru, тем самым нарушив правила сайта sql-ex.ru. Меня забанили там. Я попытался удалить свой вопрос здесь, но у меня не получилось - он пометился, как удаленный, но все равно существует. Как его удалить полностью? Если что, вот ссылка на вопрос: [Не могу понять, что вывелось в результате SQL запроса (INNER JOIN). Почему так много записей?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/782685/218063)

Answer (score 11):

Полностью удалить вопрос нельзя. Но вы уже сделали достаточно:

- вопрос теперь видят только модераторы и участники с [10к репутации](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools);
- обычным поиском по сайту вопрос не найти;
- поисковики его не индексируют — это главное для sql-ex.

Comment: Ну и сам автор ещё :)

Comment: на самом деле модераторы могут удалить совсем ни или CM точно

Comment: @Grundy модераторы могут исправить исходник (ревизию). Но, я думаю, это не тот случай.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, удалить тоже могут, было в ответах на выборах модераторов enSO :)

Comment: @Grundy вот моё меню на этом вопросе. Не вижу, как можно удалить этот вопрос больше, чем он уже удалён. https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZZB0.png

Comment: Да, вероятно я перепутал с [удалением ревизии](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/337571/2881286) хотя там еще пишут про диссоциацию пользователя и вопроса

Comment: @Grundy в диссоциацию может только CM

Comment: @NickVolynkin, возможно он и удалять по настоящему может.